# WDT & Software RESET in ESP8266 + Arduino IDE

Tags: arduino-ide, esp8266, timers, reset

I am working on ESP8266 in Arduino IDE. I want to know how to Software RESET the ESP8266. Any sketch/example would be useful. Moreover, how to initialise WDT in ESP8266.

Kindly help!

Answer (score 3):

Software reset in ESP8266 is achieved using `ESP.reset()`

as per WDT, the other answer has info on that, i.e. software WDT is cleared using `yield()` - hardware WDT is not accessible through software